# Error 404 Raised by a View

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

When I click on the laboratory link to open a form to add information to it, I get this error.
I have change the url to call a diferente view and still get the same error. Can someone tell me what may be happening? Is not the view, cause as you see I use it for other urls and in those It works perfect.

```
Page not found (404)

Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/services/laboratory/A7509006-01
Raised by:  services.views.CreateService
```

template.html

```
<td>
  <a href="{% url 'services:createexternalservice' lab=lab.credential %}" class="btn btn-default"> External Service</a>
 </td>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    'services.views',

url(r'^create/$', CreateService.as_view(),
    name='createexternalservice'),

url(r'^imagenology/(?P<aut_img_pk>\d+)/(?P<exam_id>\S+)/create/$',
    CreateService.as_view(),
    name='createexternalservice'),

url(r'^laboratory/(?P<lab>\S+)$', CreateService.as_view(), name='createexternalservice'),
```

Comment: Are you sure the requested value `A7509006-01` matches your regular expression ?

Comment: Please show your view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Your URL endpoints all have the same name* - `createexternalservice`. This is confusing the URL routing system and [there is no guarantee](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) which URL would be called when you look it up by name. Assign them different names instead.

Comment: I will *never* for the life of me understand why using the same route name twice is not an immediate runtime error in *every* routing framework.